# Output tag array for current post

Tags: wordpress, tags

I'm trying to output the tags (as an array) for the current post.

I have the ID for the current post stored  in `$post_id` e.g 18

I've attempted to get the post tags in `$tags` with the following:

```
$tags = get_tags($post_id);
```

However when I output this (with a var_dump) I find that it outputs **all** tags that exist on the blog, not just the current post.

E.g

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[116]
      public 'term_id' => string '10' (length=2)
      public 'name' => string '2648' (length=4)
      public 'slug' => string '2648' (length=4)
      public 'term_group' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'term_taxonomy_id' => string '10' (length=2)
      public 'taxonomy' => string 'post_tag' (length=8)
      public 'description' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'parent' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'count' => string '3' (length=1)
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[118]
      public 'term_id' => string '12' (length=2)
      public 'name' => string 'craft fair' (length=10)
      public 'slug' => string 'craft-fair' (length=10)
      public 'term_group' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'term_taxonomy_id' => string '12' (length=2)
      public 'taxonomy' => string 'post_tag' (length=8)
      public 'description' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'parent' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'count' => string '1' (length=1)
  2 => 
    object(stdClass)[1731]
      public 'term_id' => string '11' (length=2)
      public 'name' => string 'knitting' (length=8)
      public 'slug' => string 'knitting' (length=8)
      public 'term_group' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'term_taxonomy_id' => string '11' (length=2)
      public 'taxonomy' => string 'post_tag' (length=8)
      public 'description' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'parent' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'count' => string '1' (length=1)
```

Only key `2 =>` should show, as `knitting` is the only tag associated with this post.

Where am I going wrong?

(My next step will be to search through the tag array for a specific term, e.g knitting or sewing, so I can show a different icon based on the tag)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer for anyone interested was to use `get_the_tags` instead, with the post ID too:

```
$tags = get_the_tags($post_id);
```

This gives an array with just the tags for this post.